# reject all requests where header value is not "US"

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to block all countries except for the people in the USA trying to access my website. I tried to search for country block rules for .htaccess but could not find any. Is there a simple line of code I could add in my .htaccess file to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A sufficiently sophisticated user can set their headers to be whatever they want, and IP address geolocation can be spoofed or just plain wrong.

Comment: Is there another route to take instead of going .htaccess or should I just assume that this kind of prevention is impossible because of the IP spoofing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an api service or offline service like: http://freegeoip.net/.
They have an API for 10000 requests per hour.
if you need more, you can buy from [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-country-database) the GeoIP2 Country Database.

But if the user wants to enter your site he can with a simple proxy. there is no 100% proof.

Good Luck :)